# AWS Lambda Python function remove trailing unicode

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use a Python 3.6 AWS Lambda function to parse Windows logs sent from Cloudwatch.

These arrive in Lambda as JSON, so I extract the field I want using:

```
for i in data['logEvents']
   message = json.dumps((i['message']))
```

which gives me this in my `message` string:

```
"<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name='Lfsvc'/><EventID Qualifiers='0'>2</EventID><Level>4</Level><Task>0</Task><Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2018-04-03T15:33:57.186213000Z'/><EventRecordID>25371</EventRecordID><Channel>System</Channel><Computer>EC2AMAZ-1KJC0H1</Computer><Security/></System><EventData></EventData><RenderingInfo Culture='en-US'><Message>Geolocation positioning has been disabled by the user.</Message><Level>Information</Level><Task></Task><Opcode>Info</Opcode><Channel></Channel><Provider></Provider><Keywords><Keyword>Classic</Keyword></Keywords></RenderingInfo></Event>\u0000"
```

I am then trying to turn this string into XML to use with either xmltodict or xml.etree.ElementTree, but both of those return a malformed XML error because of the `\u0000` at the end.

So I then run this to remove the unicode:

```
xml = re.sub(u'(\u0000)', "", message)
```

which works fine on my computer in my local python console, and bothxmltodict & xml.etree.ElementTree can then work with the newly created `xml`string.

But when I run the `re.sub` command in the Lambda function, the `\u0000` remains at the end of the string.

Am I missing something obvious??

Adding the full output of `print(i['message'])`

```
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name='Service Control Manager' Guid='{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}' EventSourceName='Service Control Manager'/><EventID Qualifiers='16384'>7036</EventID><Version>0</Version><Level>4</Level><Task>0</Task><Opcode>0</Opcode><Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2018-04-03T15:31:31.854941100Z'/><EventRecordID>25365</EventRecordID><Correlation/><Execution ProcessID='712' ThreadID='4768'/><Channel>System</Channel><Computer>EC2AMAZ-1KJC0H1</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data Name='param1'>Volume Shadow Copy</Data><Data Name='param2'>running</Data><Binary>5600530053002F0034000000</Binary></EventData><RenderingInfo Culture='en-US'><Message>The Volume Shadow Copy service entered the running state.</Message><Level>Information</Level><Task></Task><Opcode></Opcode><Channel></Channel><Provider>Microsoft-Windows-Service Control Manager</Provider><Keywords><Keyword>Classic</Keyword></Keywords></RenderingInfo></Event>\u0000
```

Many thanks,
Dave

Comment: What does `i['message']` initially contain before it gets parsed using `json.dumps`? `json.dumps` might be giving you weird values when its parsing actual log values which renders your `re.sub` invalid.

Comment: Hi Clarence, not sure if this gives you the info you need, but if do a `print(i['message'])` within the Lambda, it gives me the same (albeit unformatted) output as the json.dumps, also with the `\u0000` at the end, eg `</Keywords></RenderingInfo></Event>\u0000`

Comment: Hmm, my concern is that what you get from `i['message']` is already a valid string and you don't really need to do `json.dumps`

Comment: Thanks Clarence.. I've added the full output of `print(i['message'])` to my post above..  just to also add that this works OK in my local console, it's only when I run the `re.sub` within the Lambda itself that it doesn't strip off the unicode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're issue might be caused by the use of `json.dumps` on the message string before doing `re.sub`. See example below:

```
import re, json

msg = "</Keywords></RenderingInfo></Event>\u0000"
xml_1 = re.sub(u'(\u0000)', "", msg)
print(xml_1)

message = json.dumps(msg)
xml_2 = re.sub(u'(\u0000)', "", message)
print(xml_2)
```

Output

```
</Keywords></RenderingInfo></Event>
"</Keywords></RenderingInfo></Event>\u0000"
```

As you can see in the outputs it seems like that json.dumps introduces a *double-quote* to the message which causes a problem with your `re.sub`

Comment: Perfect! I now have an OrderedDict, which is the dict we all strive for :-)  - snip `OrderedDict([('Event', OrderedDict([('@xmlns', 'http://schemas.mic` Many thanks mate